# How to fragment a character string in Linux/Unix Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

What I have stored in a variable, example xyz:

**20170629**

What I want to print:

**2017 06 29**

How I can do it:

> ```
> year=$(echo $xyz | cut -c1-4)
> month=$(echo $xyz | cut -c5-6)
> day=$(echo $xyz | cut -c7-8)
>
> echo $year $month $day
> ```

I need to know a more lazy way of accomplishing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Built in bash [substring manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
 echo ${xyz:0:4} ${xyz:4:2} ${xyz:6:2}
```

That will echo out substring from position 0 for length 4 (the year), then from position 4 for length 2 (month), and finally from position 6 for length 2 (day).

Or with the `date` command:

```
date -d'20160629' "+%Y %m %d"
```

Where we feed it the input date and give it a new format. Check the `date` manpage with `man date` to see all the format options.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Appreciate your crisp answer.

Answer (score 0):

In POSIX shell you can use:

```
$ echo $(expr substr "$var" 1 4) \
       $(expr substr "$var" 5 2) \
       $(expr substr "$var" 7 2)
```

If you are working in bash, the *string indexing* is optimal, but for `shell` which generally implies POSIX shell, *string indexes* are not available.